# Subtract 1 From Query Result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT count(P.pID)
FROM Department D, Professor P
WHERE D.dID = ? AND P.dID = D.dID;
```

I would like to subtract '1' from any result for `count(P.pID)` . So for instance if value of P.pID is 10, it would output 9... ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT count(P.pID) - 1 as pID_count 
FROM Department D, Professor P 
WHERE D.dID = ? AND P.dID = D.dID;
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
SELECT count(P.pID) - 1
FROM Department D, Professor P
WHERE D.dID = ? AND P.dID = D.dID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(P.pID)-1
FROM Department D, Professor P
WHERE D.dID = ? AND P.dID = D.dID;
```